# Programmatically create a 3D prism from location of its vertices

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a project in Unity 4.6. I am wondering if there is an easy way to programmatically set the vertex locations. Currently my code looks like this (C#):

```
public void createPoints(float x, float y, float z) {
    point [0] = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
    point [1] = new Vector3 (x, y, -z);
    point [2] = new Vector3 (x, -y, z);
    point [3] = new Vector3 (x, -y, -z);
    point [4] = new Vector3 (-x, y, z);
    point [5] = new Vector3 (-x, y, -z);
    point [6] = new Vector3 (-x, -y, z);
    point [7] = new Vector3 (-x, -y, -z);
}
```

Where x, y, and z are predetermined values and point is a `Vector3[]` (array). The prism's centre is to be point `0,0,0` (`Vector3(0,0,0)` in Unity).

As an example, using the following values:

- x = 1
- y = 2
- z = 3

The points generated should be the following (**order does not matter**):

1. (1,2,3)
2. (1,2,-3)
3. (1,-2,3)
4. (1,-2,-3)
5. (-1,2,3)
6. (-1,2,-3)
7. (-1,-2,3)
8. (-1,-2,-3)

My question: Is there a way to generate these points without practically hardcoding the values in?

My current code for the desired solution is:

```
public void createPoints(float originalX, float originalY, float originalZ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //8 vertices exist of a rectangular prism
        point [i] = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
    }
}
```

How do I change this code to generate these positive and negative points? My guess is some sort of alternation between positive and negative values for x, y, and z, using modulus of `i` or rounding of the division of `i` by some other integer, however I cannot wrap my brain around it. C# or UnityScript are OK.

In other words, in each iteration of the for loop, `x = -x`, for each something `y = -y`, for each something `z = -z`.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend changing the title. It may be misleading. Most people won't even read your post and will close it because it's "opinion based" since you used the term "best way"

Comment: Thank you, I have just edited the title and removed "Best way"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use linq for this

```
var alt = new[] { 1, -1 };
var result = ( from i in alt
               from j in alt
               from k in alt
               select new Vector3(i * 1, j * 2, k * 3)
              ).ToList();
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how this works, but it does, kudos!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with nested `for` loops like so:

```
List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            points.Add(new Vector3(i == 0 ? originalX : -originalX,
                                   j == 0 ? originalY : -originalY,
                                   k == 0 ? originalZ : -originalZ));

Vector3[] point = points.ToArray();
```

There probably is an easier, cleaner way to do this, but it does work.

Comment: I've just come up with this: `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (i % 4) {
        x = -x;
    }
    if (i % 2) {
        y = -y;
    }
    z = -z;
    point[i] = new Vector3(x,y,z);
}` (copy paste to http://jsfiddle.net and hit tidyup to see it cleaner. I'm not sure how each would affect performance, would you have any idea?

Comment: I've created a fiddle with the code from my comment above here: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/260quLL0/

Comment: What you have does work, but it does not create them in the same order. If order does not matter, either would work, but with yours you would need to order them afterwords if order does matter. As for performance, if order does not matter yours is faster, but if order does matter I got mine to run faster on average (although by 0.0005 seconds). Long story short, either would work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how if my Unity syntax is correct, but this code should be modifiable to work there. Basically, it gives you 8 vectors. The x values are x, -x, x, -x, ... The y values are y, y, -y, -y, y, y, ... and the z values are z, z, z, z, -z, -z, -z, -z.
This is done by multiplying by -1 to even and odd powers.

```js
function createPoints(x, y, z) {
  var resp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    var vect = new Vector3d(x * Math.pow(-1, i), y * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(i / 2)), z * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(i / 4)));
    resp.push(vect);
  }
  return resp;
}

createPoints(1,2,3);
```